# How to find one <td> value,when the other <td> vlaue known to me?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

The below is a part of an webpage content:

```
<td><a href="/aems/example.com">TEST LTD</a></td>
<td>SFFFFGG, JHFUJ, Hawaii,</td>
<td>aaaa</td>
```

If i know `aaaa` ,anyway can I find the value `TEST LTD`? Where `TEST LTD` can be any run-time value,where as `aaaa` always known to me. more `<td>` can be there in the web-page before or after the part of the `html` content of the above mentioned.

***EDIT***

**CODE**

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "https://www.example.com"

element = driver.find_element :name => "username"
element.send_keys "######"
element = driver.find_element :name => "password"
element.send_keys "######"
element.submit
element = driver.find_element(:name, "btnHome")
element.click
element=driver.find_element(:link, "Suppliers")
#print element.attribute(:href)
element.click
element = driver.find_element :name => "search.locationIdentifier"
element.send_keys "H00371101"
element = driver.find_element :name => "btnSearch"
element.click

# all_table_data = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "td")

 # all_table_data.each do |td|

   # puts td.text

 # end

 element2 = driver.find_elements(:xpath,"//td[text()='H00371101']/preceding-sibling::td[2]")

puts element2
```

***error has been removed but the  value was not being printed.***

Comment: I am getting error,see my **EDIT**

Comment: can you please post your code here?

Comment: You need to show code you've written. Without it we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: Let me give it a try again,otherwise I will post the code!

Comment: @theTinMan see my code! but not getting anything value from the last `print`.

Comment: updated the answer for your needs...

Comment: Print statement not working,but i want to have the `text` value, so how to access that? please advice me

Comment: use getText() method to find the text inside node, i.e. in your case it will be the contents of td. if you want anchor tag contents, append /a to xpath.

Comment: No,I want `<td>` content only.. but not getting :(

Comment: Have you seen my updated code? that `print` not giving any value, again `element1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='H00371101']"))` also nothing printed.

Comment: Do you need to use Selenium for testing or are you trying to scrape the site? If you are only scraping, don't bother with Selenium and instead, use OpenURI with Nokogiri to parse and extract elements.

Comment: @theTinMan Could you please do change on my code as per your sugesstions?

Comment: You need to show an attempt to change the code.

Comment: @theTinMan Okay I will! And if I stuck,will post here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the xpath selector. You can find the element with specific contents as,

```
 element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='aaaa']"))
```

and specific content with preceding sibling as,

```
 element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='aaaa']/preceding-sibling::td[2]"))
```

Now you can perform whatever operation on element2 that you want.

I would like to suggest you to use inspect xpath with firebug and xpath checker.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Could you give me the documentation link? what I found over net doesn't have such siblings concept.

Comment: I didn't get your last element! Could you explain it a bit? means the siblings concept!

Comment: what you actually looking for? **preceding-sibling** is xpath expression to select the preceding sibling element from the given element. search for xpath selector to know more...

Comment: I used  the [doc](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) where such i didn't find such concept. So could you guide me a link where I can get the concept,being a newbie I am unaware of the concept!

Comment: with web driver you can use, findelement and byxpath method in following way, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='aaaa']/preceding-sibling::td[2]"));

Comment: I want to see the documentation you have followed , i want to read the concept of the `siblings`. please share. I am confused with the line `xpath("//td[text()='aaaa']/preceding-sibling::td[2]`

Comment: follow this link, http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp to know more about xpath

Answer (score 0):

Here

You can try with this XPath

```
String xpath="//a[@href='/aems/example.com']/../following-sibling::td";

int td_size=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size();

for(int i=1;i<=td_size;i++)
{
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/aems/example.com']/../following-sibling::td["+i+"]")).getText());
}
```